# Unreal Online Subsystems NULL not working, Online Subsystem Steam working

Tags: unreal-engine4, steam

I'm running into an odd issue regarding the Online Subsystem NULL. I am able to create and join sessions just fine. Once I join the session all client's pawns are experiencing a rubber band effect upon movement. There is also other odd behavior such as clients returning null when getting the GameState class.

The odd thing is everything works fine and as expected using the Online Subsystem Steam. Testing on two separate computers logged into separate steam accounts the rubber band movement problem goes away and the odd behavior of clients getting null for the GameState class does not exist.

I release this would be a bigger issue if the cases were reversed. Development is just taking longer due to this issue.

When changing between the Steam and NULL Subsystems I change the following in the DefaultEngine.ini file

**NULL**

```
[/Script/Engine.GameEngine]
 +NetDriverDefinitions=(DefName="GameNetDriver",DriverClassName="OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetDriver",DriverClassNameFallback="OnlineSubsystemUtils.IpNetDriver")

[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=NULL

[OnlineSubsystemSteam]
bEnabled=false
SteamDevAppId=480

[/Script/OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetDriver]
NetConnectionClassName="OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetConnection"
```

---

**Steam**

```
[/Script/Engine.GameEngine]
+NetDriverDefinitions=(DefName="GameNetDriver",DriverClassName="OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetDriver",DriverClassNameFallback="OnlineSubsystemUtils.IpNetDriver")

[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=Steam

[OnlineSubsystemSteam]
bEnabled=true
SteamDevAppId=480

[/Script/OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetDriver]
NetConnectionClassName="OnlineSubsystemSteam.SteamNetConnection"
```

---

Are there any other settings in the DefaultEngine.ini file that need to be changed for the Null Subsystem for function correctly? Thanks!